# How to make a basic event calendar with javascript, jquery, html and css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calendar

I've been trying to build a basic calendar with some already predefined events on it. For this calendar there shouldn't be an option to add an event, meaning the events should be already defined in the code.

I've already tried to use jquery datepicker but I can't add events to it, I was only able to change the color of a few days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://fullcalendar.io/
Try out this plugin, it should fit your needs.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false
    // put further options and callbacks here
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I only have 1 problem with this "full calendar" it allows the user to drag and drop the event to another day. I'm currently trying to solve this so it stays fixed on that day.

Comment: this should be configurable, wait a sec... yes there is an option: `editable`set it to false.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out like a minute ago xD. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem... but you could up vote my answer to be even more thankfull! :-P Oh my god... i feel kind of bad for that comment. :D

Comment: I would if I could, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: i gave u some with my upvote ;) not the supposed use of upvotes but i think it is legitimate. ;)